Looking for a young adult book about a shapeshifter, but I cannot remember much about it
I read this book as a young adult and cannot remember many details. The main character is a young woman who can turn into a dragon/wyvern like creature. I think they had a specific name for what they were, but they were basically human sized dragons. I think she also lived by the ocean. Her family had this set of jewels as well that each of them were basically assigned to based on what color they were when they transformed to their dragon form. The main characters was amber. I think she also had red hair in human form? There were multiple of these shapeshifting families that lived near her if I remember correctly because she had a few friends that she would shapeshift and swim with. At some point this family comes and starts poaching them and she goes on a mission to find her friend I think? Or she is the one who gets captured and then she has to escape. I think she was also more valuable because her coloration was more rare or something. I think amber was a rare color and the rest were more earthy toned when they shifted.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is this the same story as this question?  When did you read this?

I am not sure if it's the same it could be. I had to have read it at least 10 maybe 15 years ago. The Jennifer scales book that you mentioned does not sound quite right. I also think the main character's father in the book I am looking for is missing or dead.
